# Understanding for-loop increment part

Tags: c++

Can someone tell what does this mean in for loop.I had seen it somewhere but was not able to understand it.

```
for (int i = p; i >= 0; i = ((i + 1) & i) - 1){
  //DO SOMETHING
  }
```

I want to ask meaning for this i = ((i + 1) & i) - 1.How is decrement going here am not able to get it.

Similar to this their is one more i faced :

```
  for (int i = p; i < 5; i = (i + 1) | i){
  //DO SOMETHING
  }
```

What i = (i + 1) | i means here ?
Please explainc++

Comment: `&` and `|` are bitwise operations. You can use google or any (good) C++ book to read more about them. Are take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) for a first step.

Comment: If nothing else, you can do some examples. What does `i` become when it's at 1? How about 2? And so on. Find a pattern.

Comment: @chris Can you help me modify this increment/decrement part as am not able to do it

Comment: What is the purpose of the program? What input can be? MOD=? array[x][y] is? ....strange logic to sum strange numbers, looks like some 'find primes' or similar algo.

Comment: @firda I just want to know meaning of increment/decrement part.Do the remaining logic make any difference?

Comment: Yes, very much.  Specifically, where p comes from, and what its ranges will be.

Comment: @user3923257 check my answer. It might help

Comment: The second one flips lowest-order 0-bits in `i` one at a time. You get a signed-overflow (UB) for -1, thus also if you start the loop with a negative number. If your implementation says signed-integer overflow is ok, you get an infinite loop then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is in Java, however similar behavior can be expected in C++, C

On closely observing the first loop

```
int p = 29; // 30th element if zero indexed
for (int i = p; i >= 0; i = ((i + 1) & i) - 1) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i + 1, 2) + " : " + (i + 1));
}
```

output :

```
11110 : 30          -> 30th element    30 -> 16 + 8 + 4 + 2
11100 : 28          -> 28th element    28 -> 16 + 8 + 4
11000 : 24          -> 24th element    24 -> 16 + 8
10000 : 16          -> 16th element
```

Observe the bit pattern

Similarly for second loop

```
int p = 2; // 3rd element if zero indexed
for (int i = p; i < 100; i = (i + 1) | i) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i + 1, 2) + " : " + (i + 1));
}
```

Output :

```
11 : 3          -> 3rd element
100 : 4         -> 4th element
1000 : 8        -> 8th element
10000 : 16      -> 16th element
100000 : 32     -> 32nd element
1000000 : 64    -> 64th element
```

Again observe the bit pattern.

The only place where I have seen such bit pattern is while build dependency tree like Fenwick tree or Bit Indexed Tree.

Check : http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees

In the link I guess they have assumed 1-indexed but here 0 indexed hence i adapted position of elements

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]

The logic below happened to work in one case, but not all cases.  This answer is not complete, since a fair bit of additional information has come out...

The & is a bitwise AND (as opposed to && which is a logical AND).  Following through the logic:

```
 0110 (6)
+0001 (1)
=0111 (7)
&0110 (6)
=0110 (6)
-0001 (1)
=0101 (5)
```

So, basically, it's a bunch of additional logic to get you right back where you started before subtracting the one ;)

You should be able to follow the same logic for the second problem (| is a bitwise OR).

Comment: So you mean its just i=i-- ?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.  Or i=-1, whichever is your poison :)

Comment: @user3923257, Not `i = i--`. That's actually very bad.

Comment: @chris: Yes, you're right, it is bad!  I should go to bed :p

Comment: @roelofs i=-1 are you sure ?Because later in code it was used as array index.So i think their is something wrong

Comment: @roelofs, You can't take one example and say it always works because that one example works. Allow me to give a counterexample. Start with 7 (`0b0111`), add one => `0b1000`, bitwise AND: `0b1000 & 0b0111 == 0b0000`, subtract one.

Comment: @roelofs Is their easy way to do this ?Please add modified loop statement in your answer

Comment: @chris: The logic made sense in my head, and I just picked a number to illustrate it.  Trying to figure out what the use case here might be now. Original poster - can you perhaps post the code inside the for loop as well?

Comment: @roelofs, Adding one flips bits from the right up to and including the first unset bit. The bitwise AND zeroes all of the flipped bits, so you're left with bits left of the first zero from the right. Subtracting one causes the rightmost set bit to now be unset and all of the bits zeroed by the AND to be set.

Comment: @roelofs I modifed the post to include code in it.Please check

Comment: The loop as it is will just iterate three times.  Well spotted @chris.  I can't see any logic behind it though, as it will be dependant on the initial value of i.  The changed code suggests that there is a rather more intricate interaction at play.

Comment: @roelofs Say i=100 at start.Can you please modify the loop to understand in easy way

Comment: @roelofs, It's helpful for quickly figuring out what `i` will be next time, but I'm not sure what it means without actually having a list of inputs and outputs to spot a pattern from.

Comment: Sorry user3923257 - it seems that it's not just a simple subtracting for loop - the number of times the loop cycles, is dependent on p, and we don't know where that comes from (or the range it will be, etc).  Is there a particular reason you're trying to understand the code?

Comment: I fear we'd need a lot more information to provide a good answer.  Sorry my friend :(

Comment: @chris: starting from 100, the sequence of numbers before the loop exits is 99, 95, 63.  It will exit at 63 (with different interrim numbers) all the way down to about 70 for i.

Comment: @roelofs, Yeah I messed up.

Comment: @chris, no worries - I beat you to that one ;)